# javascript: Ajax XMLHttpRequest - File not gettin loaded on the Chrome and IE8

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

Regarding this error [in image], I surfed the internet and applied all the techiniques such as [Error in Chrome only: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file URL No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012385/error-in-chrome-only-xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-url-no-access-control-all), still, it is not working in my local. Am just trying to get the JSON file from system local [D:/somefolder]. Any help? please

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/json; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="serverReply"><b><a href="#"  onclick="getMessage();">Get message</a></b></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getMessage()
{
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {

      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

  }else
  {

    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

        document.getElementById("serverReply").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    }
  }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","carousel-data.json",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Error that I am getting now]

Comment: I hope that you are using some server.

Comment: Am sorry, I haven't used any server, I just need this to work in file://, I just have the json file in my system local.

Comment: And .... he's not, the error clearly shows a file protocol, and as noted, ajax doesn't work on different protocols, ports etc.

Comment: Please use a server.

Comment: But, the same code is working perfectly on Firefox.

Comment: as the error shows, you can't do cross domain for file:// protocal. use a local server like mamp/wamp or node

Comment: @Sakthivel In your chrome, open properties, go to target and paste `--disable-web-security` at  the end...

Comment: @Rakesh,Tell me clearly bit more on this, I am not getting you properly

Comment: @Sakthivel If you are on Windows, go to shortcut of google chrome, probably on desktop, right click, go to properties, in Target input, after this `..\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` , add `--disable-web-security`.