# CORS Issue in Chrome Developer Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cors, google-chrome-devtools

I am a novice in Chrome Extension Development and I am developing a Chrome **Developer** Extension (appears as a part of Developer Tools).
This requirement is to make External Service (some URL )call which may or may not be in the same Server (of origin). From the documentation I see the extensions are not restricted by the Same Origin Policy. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

However I am running into CORS issue while I try to call an external service.

The Manifest.json looks like the below one, where I have permission to all websites.

```
"permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "clipboardWrite",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
```

In the code I am trying to call HTTP POST on some URL , the code looks like

```
gwUrl = 'http://services.odata.org/V2/(S(lts2i32bwwy01zoq4cxyscwt))/OData/OData.svc/Products';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", gwUrl , true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {}
xhr.send({ "ID":17, "Name": "Bread", "Description": "Whole grain bread"});
```

I am getting the following Error.

*OPTIONS http//services.odata.org/V2/(S(lts2i32bwwy01zoq4cxyscwt))/OData/OData.svc/Products 501 (Not Implemented)*

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load http//services.odata.org/V2/(S(lts2i32bwwy01zoq4cxyscwt))/OData/OData.svc/Products. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://cdcbiglainpfeapfejdjdkldcehjakfi' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 501.*

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U55gV.png) 
Can anyone please guide me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try adding [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#The_HTTP_response_headers) header. The response header indicates whether the response can be shared with resources with the given origin.

You may want to also check [Using CORS](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) tutorial for better understanding. This tutorial mentioned about the need to include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in all valid CORS responses and omitting the header will cause the CORS request to fail.

Solutions given in the following SO posts might also help:

- [Error in Chrome only: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file URL No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012385/error-in-chrome-only-xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-url-no-access-control-all)
- [XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)
- [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)